# If a set $S$ can be partitioned into $\mathfrak{n}$ amorphous sets, can $S$ be partitioned into $\mathfrak{m}$ infinite sets?

Tags: set-theory

Assume $\sf{ZF}$. A set $A$ is *amorphous* if it is infinite and not the disjoint union of two infinite sets. The existence of an amorphous set is inconsistent with $\sf{ZFC}$ (even $\sf{ZF}+\sf{AC}_{\omega}$).

The statement $P_{F}(\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{m})$ where $\mathfrak{n}$ and $\mathfrak{m}$ are cardinals is defined as follows:

> Let $A_{i},i\in I$ be a collection of pairwise disjoint amorphous sets where $|I|=\mathfrak{n}$, and let $A=\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_{i}$. Then there exist nonempty pairwise disjoint sets $B_{j},j\in J$ with $|J|=\mathfrak{m}$ such that $A=\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}B_{j}$.

Similarly, the statement $P_{I}(\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{m})$ is defined as

> Let $A_{i},i\in I$ be a collection of pairwise disjoint amorphous sets where $|I|=\mathfrak{n}$, and let $A=\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_{i}$. Then there exist pairwise disjoint infinite sets $B_{j},j\in J$ with $|J|=\mathfrak{m}$ such that $A=\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}B_{j}$.

Lastly, the statement $P_{A}(\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{m})$ is defined as

> Let $A_{i},i\in I$ be a collection of pairwise disjoint amorphous sets where $|I|=\mathfrak{n}$, and let $A=\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_{i}$. Then there exist pairwise disjoint amorphous sets $B_{j},j\in J$ with $|J|=\mathfrak{m}$ such that $A=\bigcup\limits_{j\in J}B_{j}$.

For which $\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{m}$ are $P_{F}(\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{m})$, $P_{I}(\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{m})$, and $P_{A}(\mathfrak{n},\mathfrak{m})$ true, false, and undecidable in $\sf{ZF}$?

Comment: In the set theory with which I am familiar, there are no amorphous sets. What theory are you working in?

Comment: I am assuming $\sf{ZF}$. The existence of amorphous sets is consistent with $\sf{ZF}$ but not $\sf{ZFC}$.

Comment: Perhaps that should be stated prominently in the body of the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think the use of the word "amorphous" is a fine indicator (although explicit mention certainly couldn't hurt) (EDIT: the OP does mention this explicitly, at the end), similarly to how "Is X equivalent to choice?" contextually indicates ZF.

Comment: Ok. It is stated at the end that I am only concerned with $\sf{ZF}$ but because $\sf{AC}$ is so widely accepted perhaps I should mention it at the beginning.

Comment: I think that this is too broad, in the sense that there can be *a lot* of variance. For example, if the amorphous sets are all "essentially the same" this is different. If all the amorphous sets are strongly amorphous, this is different. If they are not, then things may depend on additional necessary information (e.g. choice from various types of families of finite sets). Since you've been asking so many questions recently about amorphous sets, let me ask you a genuinely interested question. Where are you going with this?

Comment: I think you're right. The answer probably has a lot to do with the actual partition. I'll admit I asked this question without any answer, so I was just kind of hoping it would be nice. But what do you mean "Where are you going with this"? Why am I asking these questions? I'm curious, I guess.

Comment: Yes. But specifically, you've been asking a lot about amorphous sets. Are you planning to pursue research on amorphous sets, or combinatorics of Dedekind finite sets, or the axiom of choice, or just in general set theory, or are you just interested because you've heard about this bizarre concept of amorphous sets and you want to know more, but in a mostly superficial way of knowing the facts, and maybe some outlines of the proofs, but not any particular details?

Comment: I'd like to learn about amorphous sets and set theory in general at a deep level rather than just on a superficial one. I'm not sure if I'll formally research this stuff in college or anything but I do look for resources to do some self-studying (actually, I recently read your 5 WH's of Set Theory). What's made you curious, if I may ask?

Answer (score 2):

As a very partial answer, note that things are quite simple in the finite-index-set case for $P_A$: no nontrivial instances of the principle can hold.

Suppose $$X=\bigsqcup_{i\in I}A_i=\bigsqcup_{j\in J}B_j$$ where $A_i, B_j$ are all amorphous. Consider the function $$f: I\rightarrow J$$ sending each $i$ to the unique $j\in J$ such that $A_i\cap B_j$ is infinite. This is indeed well-defined: $A_i$ is amorphous, so we can't have $A_i\cap B_j$ and $A_i\cap B_{j'}$ both be infinite for $j\not=j'$. The function $f$ is injective, since each $B_j$ is amorphous: if $f(i)=f(i')=j$ for $i\not=i'$, then $B_j\cap A_{i}$ and $B_j\cap A_{i'}$ would be two disjoint infinite subsets of $B_j$.

By symmetry, we similarly get an injection $J\rightarrow I$, hence a bijection $I\cong J$ by Cantor-Bernstein (which does *not* require choice).

---

More generally, "finite" is really a proxy for "does not admit a finite-to-one embedding from an amorphous set," which in turn is the same as "does not have an amorphous subset." So actually we have:

> If $I\not\cong J$ and neither $I$ nor $J$ have an amorphous subset, then no set is both an $I$-fold and a $J$-fold disjoint union of amorphous sets.

Comment: Sorry, this might seem like a very simple question, but when defining $f$, how do we guarantee the existence of some $B_{j}$ such that $A_{i}\cap B_{j}$ is infinite? Wouldn't this not necessarily be true if $J$ is infinite?

Comment: Wait, upon more thought I suppose this is only a problem if $J$ satisfies certain conditions. We can use each $j\in J$ to define a piece of a partition of each $A_{i}$ by $A_{i}\cap B_{j}$ where we exclude "empty pieces". Clearly if this partition of $A_{i}$ is finite (excluding the empty pieces) then we have an infinite piece. But suppose it is infinite and $J$ can be, perhaps, linearly ordered. Then the set of pieces in the partition must also be amorphous so they cannot be linearly ordered, contradiction. However I am not sure what happens otherwise.

Comment: @P-addict Whoops, I thought $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{n}$ were finite. Editing ...